# Flutter CheckBox Size Reduce Between Two CheckBoxes

Tags: flutter, checkbox, checkboxlist

Recently, I was searching the solution to reduce the height between two checkbox in flutter that are fixed by default... But here is the solution how to do it?

Use the container and give it some height and you are good to go

```
Container(
  height: 30,
  child: CheckboxListTile(
    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
    value: mon,
    activeColor: Colors.green,
    checkboxShape: CircleBorder(),

    onChanged: (newvalue) {
      setState(() {
        mon = newvalue!;
      });
    },
    title: Text('Keep me sign in'),
  ),
  ),
```

I want to provide the solution of reducing distance between two checkboxes in flutter

Answer (score 0):

You can change some of `CheckboxListTile` properties:

```
CheckboxListTile(
            value: true,
            onChanged: (value) {},
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            dense: true,
            title: const Text('title'),
            checkboxShape: const CircleBorder(),
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
)
```